# jQuery Form Plugin - Passing and retrieve parameter to/from response method

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, ajaxform

I'm using jquery Form Plugin, method "ajaxSubmit"

```
var options = { 
        delegation:     true,
        success:        myResponse,
        url:            form_save_url,
        type:           'post'
    };  
$('#myform').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Then i have the method to handle response

```
function myResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    alert('Response caught!');
}
```

Moreover, I need to pass some parameter

```
var options = { 
        delegation:     true,
        success:        myResponse,
        url:            form_save_url,
        type:           'post'
        /* !!HERE I NEED TO PASS A PARAMETER!! /*
    };  
$('#myform').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

which I should be able to read

```
function myResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form, PARAMETER) {
    alert('Response caught!');
    alert(PARAMETER);
}
```

Is it possibile to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: link to the plugin please

Comment: [link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: did you look further into the documentation ? https://github.com/malsup/form

Comment: it looks like `data` is what you are looking for https://github.com/malsup/form#data

Comment: if you have trouble getting this to work, then provide a live example of your issue on jsbin.com and I will look into it.

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. data is useful to add POST fields, this is not exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Then you know what you have to do...